# vcvarsall.bat : Can't find header files when building

Tags: c++, visual-studio, batch-file, header-files

I'm doing a build script for my visual studio C++ solution.
i wrote a batch file that places the environment variables before running vcvarsall.bat. i'll paste the script at the end of the post.

But when it runs, It can't build the solution as **it can't find the header files**. 
*fatal error : C1083* 
They are located **in the folder Inc**. And I just don't know **how to specify it**...

script :

```
@ echo off

set PROJECT_HOME=%~dp0
set PROJECT_TOOLS=%PROJECT_HOME%\Tools


set QT_HOME=%PROJECT_TOOLS%\Qt\5.12.0\x64\5.12.0\msvc2017_64

set QT_BIN=%QT_HOME%\bin
set QT_LIB=%QT_HOME%\lib
set QT_INC=%QT_HOME%\include
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%QT_HOME%\plugins
set QT_PLATFORMS=%QT_HOME%\plugins\platforms

set PARAMS=%QT_HOME%\Params

set QML_IMPORT_PATH=%QT_HOME%\qml;%QML_IMPORT_PATH%;
set PATH=%QT_BIN%;%QT_LIB%;%QT_PLATFORMS%;%PARAMS%;%QML_IMPORT_PATH%;%PATH%

call D:\APP\Microsoft\VisualStudio_Pro\v156\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat x64 %*

devenv solution.sln /build

pause
```

Comment: set include=%include%;inc

Comment: Thank you. I added this line :
 set include=%include%;%PROJECT_HOME%\LIB_VIEW\Inc;%PROJECT_HOME%\LIB_COMMON\Inc but it doesn't help. Do I misunderstood what you said ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. The missing headers are the ones from my two dynamic libs LIB_VIEW and LIB_COMMON which are located at %PROJECT_HOME%\LIB_VIEW\Inc and %PROJECT_HOME%\LIB_COMMON\Inc. there's no doubt about it.                              So I wrote the line like this set "INCLUDE=%PROJECT_HOME%\LIB_VIEW\Inc;%PROJECT_HOME%\LIB_COMMON\Inc;%INCLUDE%" and it does not change